# How to set name for jps?

Tags: java, jvm

`Jps` gives the folowing result:

```
4673 jar
4913 Jps
292 SparkSubmit
```

How to set the `lvmid` for the first line so it outputs a given name like the 2nd/3rd instead of "jar" (the command is `java -jar xxx.jar`?

**Fixed as suggested:**
Instead of java -jar somejar.jar you can run java -cp somejar.jar some.package.Main

Comment: You can't change this. The main class is shown only for processes started by `java -cp <classpath> MainClass` and not by `-jar`. Use `jps -l` - it will show the name of .jar file.

Comment: @apangin Need to do the same thing as `SparkSubmit`, or `jps` itself (which is showing its name).

Comment: Again: you can't change this for Java processes started with `java -jar`. Run the application using classpath/modulepath syntax or create your own launcher.

Comment: Instead of `java -jar somejar.jar` you can run `java -cp somejar.jar some.package.Main`